# Mysql remove duplicate using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Hi Guys I currently have this table

MEMBER

```
**ID Position Latitude Longitute**

1   1       1.38086  103.749 
1   2       1.38086  103.749 
1   3       1.38086  103.749    
1   4       1.48086  103.949 
1   5       1.48086  103.949    
1   6       1.48086  103.949 
1   7       1.58086  103.749
```

I am current using `select * from meber group by latitude,longitute order by position desc`.

however this will result in

```
**ID Position Latitude Longitute**
1   1       1.38086  103.749    
1   4       1.48086  103.949  
1   7       1.58086  103.749
```

i wanted the result showing the highest position instead of the lowest position using the group by. any solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a subquery to determine the maximal position for each group, then join that with your select to obtain the desired records:

```
SELECT *
FROM   meber NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   latitude,longitute,MAX(position) AS position
  FROM     meber
  GROUP BY latitude,longitute
) AS t
```

Incidentally, the English word is spelled "longitude".

Comment: Please, have a look to my answer too as it may be more appropriate in some performance critical queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
select MAX(position) position,latitude,longitute
from meber
group by latitude,longitute
```

Comment: This drops the `id` - perhaps not what the OP was after?

Comment: It is unclear from the question what should happen with the `ID` column - so I omitted it. `select 1 ID,MAX(...` might also be a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery solution is the most common one.

There's another I like to use as it doesn't involve the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM member M
LEFT JOIN member N
    ON M.latitude = N.latitude
    AND M.longitute = N.longitute
    AND M.position < N.position
WHERE N.position IS NULL
```

Note that in order to get the lowest position it's as simple as writing M.position > N.position instead.